# Mixed string and variable inside jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having trouble with this code

```
  output.html('<img  width="200" src="uploads/'+response.responseText+'" height="300" >');
```

It outputs this:

```
   <img width="200" height="300" 1269050260.png""="" src="uploads/">
```

It should be:

```
   <img width="200" height="300"  src="uploads/1269050260.png">
```

I have tried many ways, for example:

```
 output.html('<img  width="200" src="uploads/'+response.responseText+'" height="300" >');
 output.html('<img  width="200" src="uploads/"'+response.responseText+'" height="300" >');
   .....
```

But when I try this:

```
  output.html("<img width='200' src='uploads/"+response.responseText+" height='300' >");
```

it gives

```
  <img width="200" 300'="" src="uploads/"1074374482.png" height=">
```

which also wrong.

**EDIT**

When I tried this suggested below:

```
   output.html("<img width='200' src='uploads/"+response.responseText+"' height='300' >");
```

I got this which is also wrong.

```
  <img width="200" height="300" src="uploads/"977165688.png"">
```

When I try:

```
    output.html("<img width='200' src='uploads/977165688.png' height='300' >"); // this works
```

Comment: I don't know if this will make a difference, but on your last example, it should be `src='uploads/"+response.responseText+"'` .You forgot to close the src.

Comment: I might try declaring a variable like `var src = 'uploads/'+response.responseText` and then in `.html()` use `"src="+src`

Comment: How certain are you of the contents of response.responseText?  If I hardcode the value of response.responseText, then your first example works just fine...

Comment: @J148 added your suggested code to my question in edit.

Comment: @J148 have tried decalring that variable also but it same result.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to just escape the " than to try and use quote rules like that. Try this:

```
output.html("<img  style=\" width: 200px; height: 300px; \" src=\"uploads/" + response.responseText + "\">");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fokjenn/2/)

If that doesn't work then you've got other problems.

**EDIT:**

Also the width and height attributes are deprecated for the `<img>` tag. Don't use them. Use CSS instead. Example has been updated

Comment: your output is this `<img width="200" height="300" 708561310.png""="" src="uploads/">`

Comment: That's what you see in the Fiddle I posted?

Comment: @your fiddle is just getting data from fiddel.shell.com but nothing shows .

Comment: That's a strange error, never seen that from jsfiddle. Try the new link.

Comment: what im suspected to see in your fiddle ?, i see just rectangular border.

Comment: Use inspect on it to check the html content of the `<img>` tag. If you have the same sort of error then you best try another browser, if that doesn't work then you better try another computer. If it works elsewhere then you should re-install your browser. If that doesn't fix it or it breaks on another computer then you better head for the hills, the universe is breaking for you.

Comment: `<img width="200" height="300" src="uploads/Hello World">`

Comment: Then this is working. Just replace "Hello World" with something like "HelloWorld.jpg" or other img path and it would be displaying. See http://jsfiddle.net/3fokjenn/5/ for an example

Comment: it doesnt work with me , im getting same result. Im using now jquery 1.11

Comment: this is the output of your last edit `<img 1206912368.png""="" src="uploads/" style=" width: 200px; height: 300px; ">`

Comment: Please put your entire HTML `<body>` contents, your script and any CSS into a new jsfiddle and post the link. Something else is going on here.

Comment: Did you get this worked out? I'd still like to see the code in its fullness to find out what is causing such a strange error.

Comment: well , i waited for this this probplem for one day and i didnt get nothing to work with any kind of changing , so i changed my mind and done something else, i mean changed the way how i will get the responseText , But thanks for your help. I couldnt wait more to fix just this.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery html() accept a HTMLString as argument, you should try to parse it as HTML if you're not sure about `response.responseText` (and you should encode it since it will belong to a `src` attribute):

```
output.html($.parseHTML('<img  width="200" src="uploads/' + encodeURIComponent(response.responseText) + '" height="300" >'));
```

Comment: your outputs is this `<img width="200" height="300" 166748152.png""="" src="uploads/">`

Comment: Are you using jQuery OP?

Comment: @colepanike .html() is a jquery method

Comment: yes i have jquery , but this gives me `$.parseHTML is not a function`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: just used 1.11 jquery and got this result `<img width="200" height="300" src="uploads/%22555325137.png%22">`

Comment: @echo_Me so you do have double quotes `"` in your `response.responseText` variable. Well, does it work for you, or do you need to see the `"` character decoded?

Comment: well , i waited for this this probplem for one day and i didnt get nothing to work with any kind of changing , so i changed my mind and done something else, i mean changed the way how i will get the responseText , But thanks for your help. I couldnt wait more to fix just this.